# np.random.normal(1.75,0.20,1000) always returns only positive values

Tags: python, numpy, random, mean, numpy-ndarray

I have tried running `np.random.normal(1.75,0.20,1000)` multiple times and it always returns only positive values in the array.

Why does it always returns only positive values? Isn't supposed to contain some negative values too?

Comment: It's because your scale (`0.20`) is too low compared to your loc (`1.75`). Make your scale bigger or your loc smaller.

Comment: You specified a mean of 1.75 and a standard deviation of 0.2.  A negative number would be nine standard deviations below the mean, which seems quite unlikely to happen.

Comment: In order to see a negative number, with a mean of 1.75 and a sigma of 0.20, you should see a number which is 8.75 sigma away from the mean. The probability to see a number 7 sigma away from the mean is 1 in 390682215445.

Answer (score 3):

In order to see a negative number, with a `mean` of `1.75` and a `sigma` of `0.20`, you should see a number which is at least `8.75` `sigma` away from the mean.
The probability to see a number `7` `sigma` away (in both directions) from the `mean` is `1 in 390682215445`.
And the probability for `8.75` `sigma` is even less.
You are making only `1000` tries.

For probabilities: [see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)

Answer (score 1):

The standard deviation you have inserted is such that most (99.7%) of the numbers that will be drawn will be greater than (1.75 - 3*0.20) = 1.15 and smaller than (1.75 + 3*0.20) = 2.35.
Look up [this empirical rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule):

Put simply: 99.7% of the values lie within 3 standard deviation from the mean.

Answer (score 0):

Negatives are very unlikely with that, they're just too far away. When I round to one digit, even for a million (rather than your 1000) values l get a distribution like this:

```
0.8 4
0.9 32
1.0 208
1.1 1099
1.2 4991
1.3 16614
1.4 43976
1.5 92127
1.6 149513
1.7 191929
1.8 191118
1.9 150418
2.0 91883
2.1 43602
2.2 16344
2.3 4777
2.4 1142
2.5 186
2.6 35
2.7 2
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BCsMwDEPv@QofEwih3RiDwU77ktCmLNDYwfGg/frMK50uEuIJ1V3ehNfec6nEAvgpdYfYAKtZmApMtK5pkkzY4GRe9EFJbEyEp3KBI85UAhKXuNox3G9@CJfBj8MhZyZhJc@ZZfXZbh5GBwsxbJARojNH9nqo2K9q@pVmq@OQJZVmnXsYUFXOKPaPut6/)):

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

a = np.random.normal(1.75,0.20,1000000)
ctr = Counter(round(x, 1) for x in a)
for x, count in sorted(ctr.items()):
    print(x, count)
```